# Saving single parquet file on spark at only one partition while using multi partitions

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, parquet, partition, coalesce

I'm trying to save my dataframe parquet file as a single file instead of multi parts files (?? I don't know the exact term for this, pardon me. I'm stupid in English)

here is how I made my df

```
val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:postgresql://ipaddr:port/address").option("header","true").load()
```

and I have 2 ip addresses where I run different master / work servers.

for ex,

ip : 10.10.10.1 runs 1 master server

ip : 10.10.10.2 runs 2 work servers (and these work servers work for ip1)

and I'm trying to save my df as parquet file only in master server (ip1)

normally I would save the file with (I use spark on master server using scala)

```
df.write.parquet("originals.parquet")
```

then the df gets saved as parquet in both servers (obviously since it's spark)

but from now I'm trying to save the df as one single file, while keeping the multi process for better speed yet saving the file only on one side of the server

so I've tried using

```
df.coalesce(1).write.parquet("test.parquet")
```

and

`df.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("testestest.parquet")`

but the result for both are same as the original write.parquet resulting the df being saved in both servers.

I guess it's because of my lack of understanding in using spark and also the function of df, coalesce..

I was told that using coalesce or partition will help me saving the file only on one server, but I want to know why is it still being saved in both servers. Is it how it's supposed to be and is it me who understood wrongly while studying the use of coalesce?? Or is it my way of writing the scala query that made coalesce not working effectively..?

I've also found that using pandas are okay to save the df into one file but my df is very very large and also I want a fast result so I don't think I'm supposed to use pandas for big files like my df (correct me if i'm worng, please.)

Also I don't quite understand how people explain 'partition' and 'coalesce' are different cause 'coalesce' is minizing the movement of the files, can somebody explain it to me in easier way please?

To resume: Why is my use of coalesce / partition to save a paquet file into only one partition not working? (Is saving the file on one partition not possible at all? I just realized, maybe using coalesce/partition is just to save 1 parquet file in EACH partition AND NOT at ONE partition as I want)